# >4GB RAM for 32-bit machine?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, x86, kernel, ram

How can a 32-bit machine support greater than 4GB RAM? The virtual memory that can be addressed with 32-bit is 2^32 with all indirections (page table/page directories, etc.) How is this done?

Comment: See [Physical Address Extension (PAE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension): "Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature to allow 32-bit IA-32 central processing units (CPUs) to access a physical address space (including random access memory and memory mapped devices) larger than 4 gigabytes."

Comment: "[It is a common misconception that 32-bit processors and operating systems are limited to 4 GB (232 bytes) of RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier)"

Comment: Thanks. Is this also supported by architectures other than x86? Like ARM?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit PAE allows the OS to take advantage of more than 4gb of ram, user mode applications however are still restricted to a 4gb virtual address space. But can play fast and loose with mapped pages via os provided functions.

Comment: @user31986 ARM Cortex-A15 can address 1TB memory but each process is limited to 4GB, much like PAE

Comment: @Mgetz: Yes, I am aware of that. Follow the link I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit machines with more than 4GB of physical memory still can only address 4GB worth of virtual memory (pointers remain 32 bits).  Remember, however, that each process has its own set of page tables, so it's possible for each process to have a mapping of a *different* portion of physical memory - the total physical memory addressed by all processes can be larger than 4GB.

In the specific case of x86 PAE (Physical Address Extensions), putting the processor in PAE mode changes the structure of the page tables.  Instead of two-level page table scheme with 4-byte page table entries, it uses a three-level page table scheme with 8-byte page table entries.  Pages are still 4KB each, but their physical base address (stored in the page table entry) is now 64 bits.

In PAE mode, the 32-bit linear ("virtual") address is broken into 4 parts.  From the most significant bits to least significant, the first 2 bits are used as an index into the 4-entry page directory pointer table.  The entries in this table are 8 bytes each, with each containing a 64-bit physical base address for a page directory.  The next 9 bits of the virtual address are used as an index into the page directory, and again the entries in this table contain a 64-bit physical base address for a page table.  The next 9 bits of the virtual address are used as an index into the page table, with each page table entry containing a 64-bit physical base address for a page frame.  The 12 least significant bits of the virtual address are used as the byte offset within the page frame.

Comment: I am not clear how the physical base address can be 64-bit. Can you please put some light on how the 32-bit virtual address is resolved to physical address (esp. to get the 64-bit physical base address of the PTE)?

Comment: @user31986: I've edited the answer.  You can think of the PAE page table as an array with a 20-bit index (the upper 20 bits of the virtual address) containing 64-bit values (the page frame base addresses).